# In Solarwinds Orion, how to fetch the data related to the users from the orion database?

Tags: database, solarwinds-orion

I want the info related to the database table in the Orion database that gives the data related to the users.
The particular fields required of the user data are:
a. Name: String
b. Email: String
c. Account Type: String
d. Enabled: Boolean Yes/No
e. LDAP User: Boolean Yes/No
f. SAML User: Boolean Yes/No

I have installed the SWQL studio and tried various queries regarding the orion.user but in all of them I am not getting any data. I am just able to run 1 query related to user and that is from the database table Orion.usersettings.